# VBA output based on certain condition using for and if loops

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

[image]

I wish to add a specific code in the 3rd column titled as code. The code corresponding to apple will be AMF, orange will be OMG and so on. The current issue I am facing is in the code execution. When it checks for the 1st value of apple in the "Fruits" column, the loop terminates instead of going and checking for the next values of "apple" in subsequent rows. Can someone please help me out here? I have given sample code here.

**CODE**

```
Dim inmd As Integer, jnmd As String, nrows As Integer
nrows = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
     jnmd = "AMF"
     For inmd = 2 To nrows
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(inmd, 2).Value like "apple" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(inmd, 3).Value = jnmd
        End If
     Next inmd
End Sub
```

Comment: *the loop terminates instead of going and checking for the next values* Debug your code. The code looks good. Make sure `nrows` is greater than 2. And for what you want, you should consider using [Select...Case Statement (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/select-case-statement) to create a code for each fruit...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code for each fruit doesn't change based on other factors (we can't really tell from your question) - the following would work:

```
Sub test()
    Dim decode As String
    Dim nrows As Long, inmd As Long
    
    decode = "apple,AMF;orange,OMG;grape,<grapecode>;lemon,<lemoncode>"
    
    nrows = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For inmd = 2 To nrows
            For Each coding In Split(decode, ";")
                If .Cells(inmd, 2) = Split(coding, ",")(0) _
                        Then .Cells(inmd, 3) = Split(coding, ",")(1)
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: this code shows an error in my system

Comment: What error are you seeing?